# In Tableau, how to use one data source to filter another one on datasource level blend?

Tags: tableau-api

Right now I have 2 data source, one is filterSource, another is dataSource. I want to filter on the filterSource base on user's login (username).  And then apply the left over rows from filterSource to further filter on dataSource.

Say filterSource contains header filterCol1 and name; dataSource contains filterCol2 and others columns.
So the matching columns between 2 data source are filterCol1 (from filterSource) to filterCol2 (from dataSource)

So what I want to do is create 2 calculated fields.
1: create calculated fields on the filterSource base on user login name
formular: username() = [filterSource].[name]

2: create calculated fields on the dataSource base on the left over on filterSource (filterCol1 and filterCol2 are many to many from 2 different source)
formular: [dataSource].[filterCol1] = [filterSource].[filterCol2]
and now I see an error of:
[image]

So my question is, is it really doable for the case I'm describing above? If yes, how should I resolve the error above? What should be the best practice for my scenario?

link of question in tableau community: https://community.tableau.com/message/474864#474864

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set up a relationship between the two data sources (i.e. Data menu --> Edit Relationships)?

Comment: Hi Sam, I did edit the relationship (as matter of fact, I followed the turiotal http://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/data-blending-0). Thanks.

Comment: You've stumped me. You might consider posting this in the Tableau community forum site. There you can post your twb file so others can take a stab at it while looking at your workbook.